# Winter'21 Release: Corrupted Settings in Setup?

Tags: apex, setup, release, winter21, release-bug

We found that the production org of one of our clients was updated to Winter'21 last week.

Usually, release updates happen with no negative impact to the settings of an Org.

But we are sure, that this is not the case for Winter'21!

Several settings on a couple of Profiles, especially the access to APEX classes where messed up. We found out, because users complained about non-working components.

Also settings for Communities got changed or lost.

**Are we the only one with such issues?**

If anyone has suffered such Setup-issues, please let me know what kind of issues and what you have done to fix it? Is it worth to invest the time to contact Salesforce about it? In my experience it is always very time consuming to walk the way with the support. We have premier plus support on that Org in question, but even then it costs a lot of time to take care and respond to a support ticket...

If this is an issue which has happend to many Orgs, Salesforce should know. Then Salesforce should act somehow and try to prevent that this happens again with the next release...

Therefore I am asking here. Main goal of this question is to find out, if anyone else has found surprising changes in the setup and configuration loss.

Comment: There were a number of [critical updates](https://releasenotes.docs.salesforce.com/en-us/spring20/release-notes/rn_cruc.htm) this release. Have you checked the release notes to make sure you weren't affected? There were changes to communities and profiles that required administrators to take action to prevent problems with this release.

Comment: @sfdcfox very good! we will review the critical updates. Thanks a lot for that hint. From the first glance, there were APEX classes just wiped out of some (not all) Profiles. The funny thing is, that we have cloned the Profiles just a few weeks ago. The clones where not affected, but the original Profiles where affected. Simply putting the APEX classes back into the corrupted profiles made it immediately work fine again. In total I think even for a Crit-Update a somehow wired result... but yes, it could be very indirectly connected...